# How can I grab a list of all txHashes from the current/previous block with JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc, blocks

I would like to grab the list of txHashes in the current block or the previous block. I would like to grab this from a json-rpc api. Is this possible? All I found was grabbing info about the block not the actual content.

Thank you.

Comment: Basic check... Have you made transactions on the rpc? Are you retrieving data from the blocks that contain your transactions?

Answer (score 1):

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getblock
if you pass false for second parameter the returned object has a `transactions` property which contains all transaction hashes